# Declaring js var to be re-used inside a .each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a fiddle to illustrate the issue. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b0gcs5Lh/)

Here is the js:

```
    var width = 100;
    var gap = 10;
    var level = 0;


    $('.block').each(function(i){
        var top = $(this).css("top");

        if(top = level){
            var left = width * (i + 1) + gap * (i * 2);
            $(this).css({'margin-left': left - $(this).position().left});
        }

        level = top;
    });
```

My goal is to show the blocks in a row until the top val is equal to the height of the blocks, then start a new row.

thanks so much.

Comment: `if(top = level)` should be `if(top == level)`. `=` is for assignment, `==` is for comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/k4hv6gcg/). I believe this is what you want to do.

Updated caparison operator `==` and given same `top:100px` values for last 2 `DIV`.